# Python extract items of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of lists (will grow) and I don't know how many elements it has, but all the lists will have all the time the same lenth of elements.

For example if I have:

```
new=[]
new.append(users)
new.append(users_count)
new.append(users_avg)
print(new)

lst2 = [item[0] for item in new]
print(lst2)
```

In this case the output will be:

```
[['ser', 'admin', 'emma', 'paul'], [2, 10, 5, 9], [33, 37, 16, 67]]
['ser', 2, 33]
```

What it is correct, but I would like to get:

```
['ser', 2, 33]
['admin', 10, 37]
['emma', 5, 16]
['paul', 9, 67]
```

i.e the first value of each of the lists in a new list, the second value of each list, the third value of each list and so on (always will be three lists but the elements inside will grow).

Answer (score 1):

The builtin [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function is what you are looking for:

```py
users = ['ser', 'admin', 'emma', 'paul']
users_count = [2, 10, 5, 9]
users_avg = [33, 37, 16, 67]

user_tuples = [*zip(users, users_count, users_avg)]

print(user_tuples)
```

Output:

```py
[('ser', 2, 33), ('admin', 10, 37), ('emma', 5, 16), ('paul', 9, 67)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you basically want to **transpose** your nested list. one way to do that is:

```
lst = [['ser', 'admin', 'emma', 'paul'], [2, 10, 5, 9], [33, 37, 16, 67]]

transposed = list(zip(*lst))
print(transposed)
# [('ser', 2, 33), ('admin', 10, 37), ('emma', 5, 16), ('paul', 9, 67)]
```

note that the inner sequences are `tuples` now and not lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip`.

```py
res = [[*x] for x in zip(*new)]
# [['ser', 2, 33], ['admin', 10, 37], ['emma', 5, 16], ['paul', 9, 67]]
```